# Найти файлы которые указаны в переменной в заданных директориях

Tags: файлы, golang

Как мне можно найти файлы, которые указаны у меня в переменной vfiles и в заданных директориях?

Код:

```golang
var vfiles = []string{
    "vfile",
    "vfile32",
    "vfilemsx32",
}

var vdir = []string{
    "C:\\Vfiles\\Drivers",
    "C:\\Vfiles\\Objects",
}

for _, rdir := range vdir {
    ioReadDir, err := ioutil.ReadDir(rdir)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    for _, file := range ioReadDir {
        for _, vfile := range vfiles {
            if strings.HasSuffix(file.Name(), vfile) == true {println("Yes")}
        }
    }
}
```

Создает цикл в цикле, из-за чего программа проходит в одних и тех же директориях более 100 раз (смотря сколько файлов в директории), а нужно чтоб программа прошлась по указанным директориям всего 1 раз и вывела "Yes" если файл, который указан в []string массиве, существует.

Answer (score 0):

Похоже вам в самый раз https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Walk

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"
)

func checkVfiles(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
    if path == "" || info == nil {
        // опускаем пустые запросы
        return nil
    }

    if info.IsDir() {
        // пропускаем папки
        return nil
    }

    var vfiles = []string{
        "vfile",
        "vfile32",
        "vfilemsx32",
    }

    // выдираем имя файла
    dir, file := filepath.Split(path)
    // здесь ещё можно проверить чтоб файл не пустая строка

    for _, vfile := range vfiles {
        // Может быть вы имели ввиду https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#HasPrefix ??
        if strings.HasSuffix(file, vfile) == true {
            // делаем что нужно с файлом
            fmt.Println(dir, file)
            return nil
        }
    }

    return nil

}

func main() {

    var vdir = []string{
        `C:\Vfiles\Drivers`,
        `C:\Vfiles\Objects`,
    }

    for _, rdir := range vdir {
        err := filepath.Walk(rdir, checkVfiles)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("error walking the dir %s %v\n", rdir, err)
            continue
        }
    }

}
```